# Subgroup theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Theorem**: If $G$ is a group such that $H,K\leq G$, then $\langle H\cup K\rangle\leq G$. Moreover, $\langle H\cup K\rangle\leq G$ is the smallest subgroup containing both $H$ and $K$.

New to proofs.

Ideas: How would I approach this? Would I show first that if $H\subset K$, then $H\cup K=K$. Then do the same for $K\subset G$? Then, $H\cup K\leq G$? The left and right angle brackets are on $H\cup K$ is confusing me.

Comment: Concrtely, $\langle H\cup K\rangle$ consists of all finite products, each term of which is an element or inverse of an element of $H$ or $K.$

Comment: So, what exactly is the definition of $\langle S\rangle$ you're working from? Because "the smallest subgroup containing $S$" is a viable choice, and if we use it, this theorem follows immediately.